# Cant start xinit from chroot

Tags: xorg, chroot

I have been trying to run a graphical system from a debian bootstrap

What i did is create a basic bootstrap using debootstrap,
Installed openbox as a test wm,
Set Display variable according to [Arch Chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/chroot),
Run `startx /bin/openbox-session`

But it keeps saying Xorg connection broken,
And I cant find any log file of xorg in chroot,
Nor any traces of logs in host system

Answer (score 0):

As I learned how startx works, I found the way to start wm from chroot

First I created `/opt/runner` with

```
#!/bin/sh
xhost +local:
sudo -E arch-chroot .nroot/  /cinit
```

Than I created a basic init file as `/cinit` in chroot with

```
#!/bin/sh
#Replace USER with your user name
DISPLAY=:0 runuser -l USER  -w DISPLAY -c '/opt/setupUser'
```

And lastly, I created `/opt/setupUser` in chroot with

```
#!/bin/sh
#pulseaudio -D
/usr/bin/x-session-manager
```

Basicly
startx runs a script
which in turn setps up chroot and calls custom init
which in turn sets up everything inside chroot
which starts the wm

Comment: But cant get the sound working